# System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll while reading a data from Sql server in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I would like to connect to my local db on Sql Server using System.Data.SQLite in Xamarin.Forms. I ve written a code to read data but all the time I got exception: System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll.   I attach code from MainPage. (User is a model class contains auto-properties).

Target platform is set to Any CPU but change it to x86 or x64 doesnt work.

```
using SimpleDb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SimpleDb
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<User> usersCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        private string connString;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connString = @"Data Source=TOM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TracksDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
                        MultiSubnetFailover=False";

            usersView.ItemsSource = usersCollection;
        }

        private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string select = "SELECT Username,Password FROM Users";

                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(select,conn))
                {
                    using(SQLiteDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            usersCollection.Add(new User()
                            {
                                Username = rd.GetString(0),
                                Password = rd.GetString(1)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) SQLite libs are for SQLite dbs, not SQL Server, 2) connecting your mobile app directly to a SQL server is a horrible idea

Comment: @Jason So what do you prefer in this case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/